# Likelihood Ratio when true/false positive/negative rates are not available

Tags: likelihood-ratio, disease

[In this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23123231/) (PMID 23123231; paywalled), the authors develop a logistic regression prediction model for Alzheimer's disease. In **Table 3** the authors then present disease prediction results after applying the model to a validation set (the *Class* column specifies probability intervals into which the patients were split):

[image: Table 3]

I'm trying to replicate a statistical analysis I've found in a spreadsheet, where the creator of the spreadsheet has used the data from Table 3 *alone* to calculate the Positive Likelihood Ratio for different probabilities of disease predicted by the model. While I'm able to blindly follow the calculations in the spreadsheet, I'm struggling with understanding the reasoning and validity of the steps.

All similar worked examples I've found assume access to the complete validation set, making it possible to calculate the sensitivity and specificity of the model from the true/false positive/negative rates, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Is there a general procedure for this type of analysis? Any help in the form of explaining the reasoning or guiding me to some good reading material is much appreciated.